# Point inside triangle 2d

Tags: java, double, point

So I to create a method that checks if the point " ponto " is inside the triangle given by the points A,B,C as vertices.

So far I have this :

```
final double PRECISION = 0.1;
public boolean dentroDoTriangulo (Point A, Point B, Point C, Point ponto){

    //total
    double ABC = Math.abs ((A.x*(B.y-C.y)+B.x*(C.y-A.y)+ C.x*(A.y-B.y))/2);

    //parcial
    double ABP = Math.abs((A.x*(B.y-ponto.y)+B.x*(ponto.y-A.y)+ponto.x*(A.y-B.y))/2);
    double APC = Math.abs (A.x*(ponto.y-C.y)+ponto.x*(C.y-A.y)+C.x*(A.y-ponto.y))/2;
    double PBC = Math.abs (ponto.x*(B.y-C.y)+B.x*(C.y-ponto.y)+C.x*(ponto.y-B.y))/2;
    double parciais = ABP + APC + PBC ;
    return Math.abs(ABC - parciais) <= PRECISION;
}
```

I've already tried doing it like :

```
ABP +APC +PBC == ABC
```

Nothing either, can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. What specifically is your issue? Can you provide a few test cases?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Your code seems to work OK. Here's a Point class example in case that's where you are crashing.

```js
    public class Point {
      float x;
      float y;
      Point() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
      }
      Point(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
      }
    }
```

Just in case, I propose another solution:

Check out [this algorithm for determining if the point is inside a triangle](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/).

I cannot see your `Point` class so I do not know if there is a bug there. I assume it is two floats for x&y coordinates. We'll assume it's ok.

Can you explain your algorithm a bit better? I looks like you are taking three areas of the sub-triangles and adding them up to compare against the original triangle (with PRECISION tolerance). Try the "SameSide" function three times as mentioned in hyperlink if you want--which takes two cross products and then the dot product of the results of the cross products to determine if a point is on the "correct side" of a line between any two of the vertices (there are three such lines).

Code snippet for algorithm:

```js
boolean SameSide(p1, p2, a, b) {
  int[] cp1 = CrossProduct(b - a, p1 - a);
  int[] cp2 = CrossProduct(b - a, p2 - a);
  if (DotProduct(cp1, cp2) >= 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

boolean PointInTriangle(p, a, b, c) {
  if (SameSide(p, a, b, c) && SameSide(p, b, a, c) &&
    SameSide(p, c, a, b) {
      return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```

Where a, b, c are the vertices and p is the point. I recommend int [] to hold the vectors. You will need to write the helper functions to calculate vector manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

I could not follow your algorithm, but you could send out horizontal (or any direction for that matter) rays in two directions from the point. If it hits the triangle in both directions, then the point will be inside the triangle. You will need to be careful of special conditions where the ray hits a vertex. That would be considered as hitting two lines on one side. But as long as the ray hits the triangle in both directions, the point will be inside.

Answer (score 0):

So I used your code for method dentroDoTriangulo  and stuck is inside a class. I used the Point class given above. Then I called your method using the quick and dirty code given below. It seems to work without any problems. Like @TNT says above, a test case would be helpful.

```js
public class Caller {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Triangle myTraingle = new Triangle();
  boolean isInside = myTraingle.dentroDoTriangulo(new Point(1,0), new Point(3,0), new Point(2,2), new Point(2,1));
  if (isInside) {
   System.out.println("Point is inside");
  } else {
   System.out.println("Point is outside");
  }
 }
}
```